# Como definir una llave foránea opcional en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Esta es mi migración

```
Schema::create('grados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre', 120);
        $table->integer('nivel_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('nivel_id')->references('id')->on('niveles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('carrera_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('carrera_id')->references('id')->on('carreras')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  dd($request->carrera_id);
  $grados=new grado($request->all());
  $grados->save();
  flash::Success('Grado Guardado Exitosamente');
  return redirect()->route('admin.grados.index');
}
```

y estos son los div de mi vista:

```
    <div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('nivel_id', 'Nivel')!!}
{!!Form::select('nivel_id', $niveles, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=> 'Seleccione un Nivel', 'required'])!!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('carrera_id', 'Carrera')!!}
{!!Form::select('carrera_id', $carreras, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=> 'Seleccione una Carrera o deje en blanco'])!!}
</div>
```

Al intentar guardar obtengo este error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`colegiola2`.`grados`, CONSTRAINT `grados_carrera_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`carrera_id`) REFERENCES `carreras` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL) (SQL: insert into `grados` (`nombre`, `nivel_id`, `carrera_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Tercero, 1, , 2017-09-07 16:35:14, 2017-09-07 16:35:14))

Answer (score 2):

Tenés que enviar `null` en el campo `carrera_id`, actualmente le estas enviando `''`
Cambiá el Select en la vista

```
{!!Form::select('carrera_id', ['null' => 'Seleccione una Carrera o deje en blanco...'] + $carreras, null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
```